# how to use Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface class to get the current bandwidth in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, performancecounter

I wanted to how to use Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface class to get the current bandwidth.
I want to know from the begining. i'm using xp,Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition.I'm not getting how to.

Comment: By "use" I assume you mean "consume" as opposed to "provide?"

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to get the required data using the [Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371643%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API directly instead of going through WMI.  Step by step instructions are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371897%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

> After creating a query and adding
>   counters to it, call the
>   PdhCollectQueryData function to
>   retrieve the current raw data for all
>   counters in the query.
>
> Many counters, such as rate counters,
>   require two data samples to calculate
>   a formatted data value. PDH maintains
>   data for the current sample and the
>   previously collected sample. The
>   following procedure describes how to
>   collect counter values that require
>   two samples to calculate a displayable
>   value.

Both APIs are complex, there is no easy way here.

Comment: I have got a code , that uses the performance counter, but i get a error , "PdhCollectQueryData failed\n" ie . NO_DATA . I have crossed cheked with "performance" in the system , we have got "\\Network Interface(%s)\\Current Bandwidth" , but why i'm getting this error. plesase help. thanks

Comment: PWSTR COUNTER_PATH = "\\Network Interface(NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller - PacketScheduler Miniport)\\Current Bandwidth" i'm using still i'm not getting

Comment: I want to get upload and download bandwith.using performance counter i'm only getting 10000000 as the value .please tell how can i get upload and download bandwidth.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface* instead, the Raw counter needs to be processed before used and thats a non-trivial task.

The following properties may be of interest:

BytesReceivedPerSec, BytesSentPerSec, CurrentBandwidth ( to calculate utilization) , BytesTotalPerSec